# Open files with VIM in tabs instead of windows

Tags: windows, vim, tabs

I have searched and found threads related to this, but not exactly the same case.

I use VIM in Windows7. It's set as the default editor for text files.
The problem is when I click in some text file in order to open it, it is opened in a new VIM window no matter if I already have one or more VIM windows opened.

How to change this behavior?
Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**
This program solved my problem: http://defaultprogramseditor.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually set up your file associations in Windows to launch Vim with a custom command. If you're an administrator and don't mind messing with EVERYBODY's config, you can use the `ftype` and `assoc` commands in the cmd.exe shell. Otherwise, you can manually create registry entries in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`.

The registry method actually sets up the same structure that you would set up automatically with `ftype` and `assoc`. First you must create a file type like "sourcecode" under that Classes key, with `shell\open\command` key having the exact command you want to open Vim with, using `%1` in place of the file name to pass in. Then create a association key like `.c` with a value of the filetype you created, in this case "sourcecode".

Some details on file associations here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Windows_file_associations

Specifically for setting up "launch in tabs" behavior, you want --remote-tab-silent, as done here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Launch_files_in_new_tabs_under_Windows

Comment: I'm trying to do it by writing this commands in cmd:
`ftype code="C:\Program Files\Vim\vim72\gvim.exe" --remote-tab-silent "%1;"
assoc .c=code;
assoc .h=code;`
But it does not work...The paths are correct. Then I try to open some .c or .h files and it opens 2 different windows.

Comment: It's possible you already have user-specific mappings from some other method, which would make the ftype and assoc commands not do anything for your user name. It's also possible the stray ; inside the quotes is interfering, you can get rid of that. I assume you did 3 separate commands for this? I haven't tried ftype and assoc on Windows 7 to tell you the truth, because I've been using the user-specific registry area instead since before I was using Windows 7. I'm glad you found a solution though.

Comment: Yes, probably I already had user-specific mappings. I though ftype and assoc commands would override those I had previously defined. I tried to browse across the registry to edit the fields by myself but I wasn't sure about what to edit. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

vim has a "remote-server" concept, which allows you to open files in single/certain vim instance.

vim's man page (help doc too: `:h remote`) has the explanation.  in short:

```
vim --serverlist                      #list names of all found vim servers
vim --servername {name}               #current instance becomes as server named {name}
vim --servername {name} --remote file #open file in {name} vim-server
```

You can still send keys to the remote vim, when the buffer load by `--remote-send` or with command `... --remote +{cmd} file`

For your requirement, you want to open files in a vim server's tab page, you could:

```
vim --servername FOO --remote-tab yourfile
```

Comment: Just thought I'd link to the online reference of it: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html